# C# Dictionary with Named/Labeled Types

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, types

I've searched just about everywhere and not even sure it's possible, but what the hey, I thought I would see what you C# wizards might have for a solution or workaround.

TL;DR:

I have a multi-dimensional collection using C# dictionaries and want to indicate what each string in the dictionary is for, something like this:

```
private Dictionary<string: Area, Dictionary<string: Controller, string: Action>> ActionCollection;
```

Which of-course does not work. For now I'm just commenting the dictionary.

Suggestions, thoughts, ideas?

Comment: You could write a custom class that internally uses that dictionary of dictionaries to store the data, but exposes the data with more meaningfully named properties.

Comment: what about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30496921/185123)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do that, but you could add a summary.

**For example:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Dictionary<Area, Dictionary<Controller, Action>>
/// </summary>
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> ActionCollection;
```

These comments will show up in the intellisense.

---

**Or:**

If you want to extract info with reflection, you could use [custom attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx)

---

If it is just for readability, you could create [aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) for it:

```
using Area = System.String;
using Controller = System.String;
using Action = System.String;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private Dictionary<Area, Dictionary<Controller, Action>> ActionCollection;
    }
}
```

But intellisense will show `string`

---

@MMM says about invalid xml, you can do this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Dictionary&lt;Area, Dictionary&lt;Controller, Action&gt;&gt;
/// </summary>
```

Comment: Ohhh dear! I never knew you could do aliasing like this. I like this approach the best. Very nice, quite wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: In VS2019 the alias method shows the names in intellisense, but if you alias say String twice, it will show the first alias for both.

Comment: The summary method doesn't work because it is invalid XML.

Comment: [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70249042/185123)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible by using [**Tuple Field Names**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names) within List:

```cs
private List<(string Area, List<(string Controller, string Action)>)> ActionCollection;
```

That's feature from C# 7.0 or from .NET 4.3 by importing System.ValueTuple nuget.

Comment: Obviously, this uses a list instead of a dictionary, so it can have performance implications.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class that pairs the key or the value with the annotation:

```
class AnnotatedVal {
    public string Val {get;}
    public string Annotation {get;}
    public AnnotatedVal(string val, string annotation) {
        // Do null checking
        Val = val;
        Annotation = annotation;
    }
    public bool Equals(object obj) {
        var other = obj as AnnotatedVal;
        return other != null && other.Val == Val && other.Annotation == Annotation;
    }
    public int GetHashCode() {
        return 31*Val.GetHashCode() + Annotation.GetHashCode();
    }
}

private Dictionary<AnnotatedVal,Dictionary<AnnotatedVal,AnnotatedVal>> ActionCollection;
```

Now you can use `AnnotatedVal` in your dictionaries to assure segregation:

```
ActionCollection.Add(new AnnotatedVal("hello", "Area"), someDictionary);
if (ActionCollection.ContainsKey(new AnnotatedVal("hello", "Area"))) {
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("No");
}
if (ActionCollection.ContainsKey(new AnnotatedVal("hello", "Controller"))) {
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("No");
}
```

The above should produce

```
Yes
No
```

because `AnnotatedVal("hello", "Area")` and `AnnotatedVal("hello", "Controller")` use different annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each string in it's own class.  Then the declaration and intellisense will be descriptive:

```
public class Area
{
    public string area { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return area;
    }
}
public class Controller
{
    public string controller { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return controller;
    }
}
public class Action
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return action;
    }
}
private Dictionary<Area, Dictionary<Controller, Action>> ActionCollection;
```