# c# - How to create list/dictionary with descriptive members

Tags: c#, .net

I have code which has so many dictionaries like the below
`

```
//List[0] => AverageValue,List[1] => MeanValue, List[2] => Maximum

Dictionary<string,List<double>> TestValues ;

//List[0] => Sigma,List[1] => MisValue

Dictionary<string,List<double>> TestSet ;`
```

So, if you see different members of List stores different types. I want to access these names in intellisense. Like `TestSet.Sigma=0.1`. So that I won't mistakenly assign *MisValue* into *SigmaValue*. I tried to derive the class from int,but it was a sealed class. var also is not helping , Because I couldn't add it to dictionary. Tuple is not available in the .net version I am using(.net 3.5). So somebody please guide me on this.

Note: I am using visual c# express 2008.

EDIT: The company gave me "visual c# express 2008". From the first itself this application got created using this version.The application also uses 3rd party dlls. So if we change the .net version, it may affect so many things.

Comment: The answer here might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496657/give-names-to-key-and-value-in-c-sharp-dictionary-to-improve-code-readability

Comment: How about making your own class/struct?

Comment: _"`var` also is not helping"_ - note that `var` is just a placeholder for the real type. When you compile your code, `var` will be replaced with the real type.

Comment: Why use a dictionary at all? And why use C# Express 2008 when Visual Studio 2019 Community is free? And so is Visual Studio Code? Same goes for .NET 3.5, which is no longer supported - hasn't been supported for at least 5 years, closer to 10

Comment: You can't inherit from int or double not because they are sealed classes, but because they are structs. All structs implicitly inherits the ValueType and are sealed by design.

Comment: What you do once you get a current version of .NET and VS Code, depends on what your problem is. For simple cases, you could create a simple class with all those fields. If you want to do numerical analysis though you need something like [a DataFrame](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-dataframe/). Even in .NET 3.5, a DataTable (strongly-typed perhaps) would be better than a Dictionary<string,List<double>>`

Comment: @Sparkle The link you provided also not having the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing two different things here:

The first is abusing lists or dictionaries (which are arbitrary-length structures accessible by index/key at runtime) when what you want is a tuple or a simple custom struct, which is accessible by name, at compile-time, thus discouraging errors when you accidentally set to index `1` when you wanted `0`.

```
public struct TestSet
{
    double Sigma {get;set;}
    double MisValue {get;set;}
}
```

The second is that you want to avoid accidentally setting a `Sigma` into a `MisValue`, which is a question of types. Your initial approach - extending `double` - makes sense, but isn't possible in .NET as you've discovered. But you can do the same thing using wrapper types and implicit conversions:

```
public class Sigma
{
    public double Value {get; private set;}

    public Sigma(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(Sigma sigma) 
    {
        return sigma.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Sigma(double value)
    {
       return new Sigma(value);
    }
}
```

And the same for the other value types. This will allow you to assign `double` to them, but not each other. Combine that with the custom struct above for a type-safe experience:

```
TestSet set = new TestSet();
set.Sigma = 5.1;               // works - implicit conversion from double.
double sigmaValue = set.Sigma; // works - implicit conversion.
Sigma anotherSigma = set.Sigma;
set.MisValue = anotherSigma;   // doesn't compile - no implicit conversion.
```

And finally, as mentioned in the comments, using a 12 year-old platform when there have been six major revisions to the IDE and a five (I think) to the language is a recipe for frustration, as many guides and online resources will probably have been updated to C# 6, at the very least. The only reason I can think of to use it is compatibility with existing code, and the best thing to do there is update that code. VS2019 has a free community edition and VSCode is free.

Comment: There are more than 20 dictionaries with different sets of Lists. Creating classes for each list will take time and even if I do, it will confuse. I want to make it in single line , like in the declaration itself.